# How can I enumerate all keys in our Redis database?

Tags: ruby, database, redis

We have a huge Redis database containing about 100 million keys, which maps phone numbers to hashes of data.

Once in a while all this data needs to be aggregated and saved to an SQL database. During aggregation we need to iterate over all the stored keys, and take a look at those arrays.

Using `Redis.keys` is not a good option because it will retrieve and store the whole list of keys in memory, and it take a loooong time to complete. We need something that will give back an enumerator that can be used to iterate over all the keys, like so:

```
redis.keys_each { |k| agg(k, redis.hgetall(k)) }
```

Is this even possible with Redis?

This would prevent Ruby from constructing an array of 100 million elements in memory, and would probably be way faster. Profiling shows us that using the `Redis.keys` command makes Ruby hog the CPU at 100%, but the Redis process seems to be idle.

I know that using keys is discouraged against building a set from the keys, but even if we construct a set out of the keys, and retrieve that using smembers, we'll be having the same problem.

Comment: It sounds like you need a back-end database table that is used for temporary storage of the Redis data-store. I'd try periodically sweeping through the Redis DB to find records that aren't in the table and copy them over. Then I'd hit that table to aggregate and pull data into the main DB. That would keep the Redis side of the task to a minimum, and allow you to take advantage of the SQL database's iteration/aggregation capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incremental enumeration of all the keys is not possible with the current Redis version.

Instead of trying to extract all the keys of a live Redis instance, you could just dump the database (bgsave) and convert the resulting dump to a json file, to be processed with any Ruby tool you want.

See https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

Alternatively, you can use the redis-rdb-tools API to directly write a parser in Python and extract the required data (without generating a json file).

Comment: Reading 100 million JSON records from a file is going to be slurping a big file into memory just to be parsed, which will cause the same problem, only at a different stage. Outputting the data to CSV would allow reading records incrementally.

Comment: Use a streaming API to read the JSON file, or write your parser using redis-rdb-tools in Python and output CSV or your preferred data format.

Comment: For an example of JSON streaming API with Ruby, see https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby